# JavaScript function execution in object

Tags: javascript, function, object, execute

I want to add a function to some object (in a form of a variable) and execute it when i need too.
How to do this?
 Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
obj.doSomething = function()
{
  console.log('done');
}

obj.doSomething();
```

This won't affect any of obj's existing fields or methods (the obvious exception being if there's already a `doSomething`).

Answer (score 5):

```
var myFunc = function() { ... };
var myObj = { func: myFunc };

myObj.func();
```

You can also skip the `myFunc` temporary variable if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty vague, but here you go:

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = function() {
    return "baz";
};

// code...

obj.foo();
```